# How to can I have a sliding bar that slides on click in my nav bar using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

Currently, I have three tabs in my nav bar, BOARD, SKILLS, and ABOUT, all in one container with a boarder-bottom for the container. When I click on one of the divs, the appropriate div name is selected, to indicate which tab I am on. That is what is currently working and can be seen in my codePen.io:

[What I have so far - click here](http://codepen.io/csapty12/pen/XKVLdm)

[image]

```
.
```

What I am trying to do is when I go from BOARD to SKILLS or BOARD to ABOUT, is to have a bar slide from one one tab to the next, rather than being static-like (which is what I have currently) e.g. a smooth scroller on click from one tab to the next. How can I go about doing this? I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Check out google web fundamentals on animation or lava js. You could either move a div over the tabs on select or move the active tab itself.

Comment: http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/01/how-to-create-dynamic-tabs-with-lava.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to slide an element:

```
function scaleSlider(to) {
  var $slider = $('.slider', '.tabs'),
    $elSpan = to.find('span'),
    width = $elSpan.width(),
    left = $elSpan.position().left;
  $slider.animate({
    width: width,
    left: left
  });
}
```

In your HTML you need to add the `.slider` element:

```
<div class="col-md-8 tabs">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <!-- your html here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs .slider {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid grey;
}
```

So when you click a menu element you call `scaleSlider`:

```
$('.skills').on("click", function() {
    //Your code here
    scaleSlider($(this));
});
```

Please check out this demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyoBmg